# staggeredgridlayoutmanager don't show item after refresh in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

In my RecyclerView, I use StaggeredLayoutManager for show items, but when refresh with RefrefreshLAyout,but later refresh don`t show items until scroll in recyclerview, this is part the code.

```
public class NotesListFragment extends Fragment
  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, OnInternetListener, OnTapInternetDialogListener {

  private SwipeRefreshLayout notesListRefreshLayout = null;
  private ListRecyclerView notesListRecyclerView = null;
  private NotesAdapter notesAdapter = null;
  private List<Note> notes = null;

  public NotesListFragment() {
  // Required empty public constructor
  }

  public static NotesListFragment newInstance() {
    NotesListFragment fragment = new NotesListFragment();
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    notesListRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.notesListRefreshLayout);
    notesListRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    notesListRecyclerView = (ListRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.notesListRecyclerView);
    initObjects();
    showNotes(notes);
  }

  private void initObjects() {
    notesListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    if (isTablet) {
      if (((BaseActivityCompat) getActivity()).getOrientationDevice() == OrientationDevice.LANDSCAPE) {
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        notesListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        notesListRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceGridDecoration(3, 20, true));
      } else {
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        notesListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        notesListRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceGridDecoration(2, 20, true));
      }
    } else {
      final StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
      notesListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }
  }

  private void showNotes(List<Note> notes) {
    if (notesAdapter == null) {
      notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getContext(), notes, advertising,
      advertisingList, (AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), AdvertisingSection.HOME.getSection());
      notesListRecyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
      notesAdapter.setOnNoteItemClickListener(onNoteItemClickListener);
      notesAdapter.setOnNoteActionClickListener(onNoteActionClickListener);
    } else {
      notesAdapter.setUpdate(true);
      notesAdapter.refreshAdapter(notes);
      notesListRecyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
    }
  }

  public void onRefresh() {
    obtainNotesHome(true);
  }
}
```

Later the refresh with RefreshLayout implements show space null and when i do scroll the item show in recyclerview with staggeredlayoutmanager.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with your code. Try to use a placeholder image. It has worked to me.

Comment: this fragment is used in tabhostfragment, when change tab and come back at this fragment, the recyclerview not show list with items, how is lost the adapter when debug the adapter exist in memory byut not show nothing